# flask.request.remote_addr in Azure.functions

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, httprequest, azure-static-web-app

I am rewriting a PHP app to a Azure Static Web App and struggeling with some API functionality. In the old PHP Site, there are few AJAX API Calls and the API is using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to get the client IP.

I know in flask was that functionality `flask.request.remote_addr`. Is there anything in azure.functions where I currently basically the HttpRequest and HttpResponse classes and seek a easy way to get the client IP.

Any advise is welcome!

Comment: Seems like this is possible only if the the function app is using [App Service Authentication / Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=python#working-with-client-identities)

Comment: unfortunately the API usage will be anonym. Maybe I will switch to flask instead of azure.functions.httprequest/response

Answer (score 0):

In Azure functions you can use Http trigger for Http request to get the IP.
Else in python we can get it as below:

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    category = req.route_params.get('category')
    id = req.route_params.get('id')
    message = f"Category: {category}, ID: {id}"

    return func.HttpResponse(message)
```

Check for attributes and annotations from [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=python#attributes-and-annotations)